# iOS Charts(Daniel Gindi) : Library - Shaded region Stacked Lines

Tags: swift, ios-charts

Is charts shown in below images possible using Daniel Gindi iOS Stacked Lines Charts library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts
Especially that blue color diagonal shaded region.
If not with this library then any references how to achieve this with any other library or Swift Charts by Apple?
Sorry i don't know how to ask the author of this library so i'm asking here

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is wrong about the question ? I just asked has anyone used this Charts Library for such requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue is solved using CombinedChartView which has one scatter data set, and 2 line data sets. Then using fill for line dataset it was achieved stacked lines. If you are looking something like this let know maybe solution can work for you as well.[image]